# How to understand the following quote?

Tags: css

According to [W3][1],

> an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must
>   not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting
>   context as the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edited out the critical bit from the quote. The quote should be

> **The border box of** a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must
>   not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting
>   context as the element itself.

It's the border box of the BFC that must not overlap. The margin box of the BFC is not restricted.

Comment: `The border box of` Oh My poor English. I thought  it was `The border box of a table` and `The border box of` doesnt apply to the elements mentioned later.  Thanks. Now things are clear.

Comment: I think the original quote is a little ambiguous. Especially for non native speakers. A paper title reads: `Revisiting the Ambiguity of “And” and “Or” in Legal Drafting`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.float{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
  background:yellowgreen;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.bfc{
  overflow:hidden; /*establish a new bfc*/
  width:366px;
  height:400px;
  float: right;
  background:blue;
  margin-left:50px;/*overlap with div.float*/
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="bfc"></div>
```

I've decreased size of width of `.bfc` and added `float:rigth;` to the same selector.